# how to preserve transparency when scaling PNG with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to scale my PNG images, and I find the transparency turns to white after scaling.
How can I preserve the transparency? Thanks

```
ffmpeg -i background_image.png -vf scale=1080:1920 output.png
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'background_image.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, pal8(pc), 1440x2560, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to 'output.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, pal8, 1080x1920, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 png
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.113x    
video:669kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

[My Sample PNG file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VDgJ.jpg)

I don't know why my PNG file with transparency is converted to a jpg format with white after uploading to  stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rgba` as pixel format (`-pix_fmt`). In your command it would be:

```
ffmpeg -i background_image.png -pix_fmt rgba -vf scale=1080:1920 output.png
```

[This ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2158) mentions a similar problem, so I tried with [the sample image](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/attachment/ticket/2158/pal8_alpha.png) of that ticket, which is also a pal8 PNG as yours, and got these results:

Without `-pix_fmt rgba` the output file has a white background:

```
ffmpeg -i pal8_alpha.png -vf scale=1080:1920 output.png
```

With `-pix_fmt rgba` the background is transparent:

```
ffmpeg -i pal8_alpha.png -pix_fmt rgba -vf scale=1080:1920 output.png
```

Comment: Work like a charm! If I am looking for a general approach, meaning the input images could be other formats (not necessarily a pal8 PNG), does this work as well?

Comment: @Richard, I believe it would probably work, as long as ffmpeg supports the input image format. You can list the pixel formats with `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`. I guess your input images need to have a format listed with the `I` flag (Supported Input  format for conversion). In case you wanted to use an output format different from `rgba`, you can take a look at the pixel formats with the `O` flag that have 4 `NB_COMPONENTS` (3 for the colors and 1 for alpha).

Comment: You can use the format filter instead of the legacy `-pix_fmt` alias: `-vf format=rgba,scale=1080:-1`. Advantage is that you can control when and where the pixel format conversion occurs in relation to other filters (not that it really matters in this case but it can for more complicated filtergraphs). You can use `ffmpeg -h encoder=foo` to show which pixel formats the encoder supports, then look for the letter `a` in the pixel format name to see if it supports standard alpha.

Comment: Another thing is, for some images, the command `-vf format=rgba,scale=1080:-1` runs well, but for some others, the conversion fails, saying `Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'output.png'. Use '-frames:v 1' for a single image, or '-update' option, or use a pattern such as %03d within the filename.
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument`, I have to add `-frames:v 1`. 
Any ideas?

Comment: sample image is [reindeer](https://i.ibb.co/wrjFnXd/Bl3b-O4moq-L.png)

Comment: This does preserve transparency, however, the image is much bigger. In my case, resized `pal8` version is 19kB, but the resized `rgba` version is 73kB.

Is it possible to preserve transparency without converting the image to `rgba`, so that the file size doesn't increase?

Comment: @Zoxx, I think you can use the [palettegen](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen-1) and [paletteuse](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse) filters: `ffmpeg -i background_image.png -vf palettegen palette.png` and then `ffmpeg -i background_image.png -i palette.png -filter_complex '[0]format=rgba,scale=1080:1920[x];[x][1]paletteuse' output.png`.